# dynamically allocated chat array prints missing data & empty

Tags: c++

I'm parsing XML using  xerces and building an internal structure that I can later traverse.

As part of this parsing I encounter a variable number of  `<Field_Delimited>` elements that look like this:

```
<Field_Delimited>
<name>some_value</name>
<data_type>ASCII_Real</data_type>
<unit>some_value</unit>
<description>some_value</description>
</Field_Delimited>
```

**The structure in memory called `file_observational_area` that will represent these fields is declared at file level globally,** see relevant snippet, most relevant method is **get_data()**:

```
file_observational_area * _file_observational_area = NULL;

    int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

        //pass in as console argument 
        char* xmlFile = args[1];

        //initialize  file_observational_area
        _file_observational_area = allocate_file_observational_area(_file_observational_area, 1);
        //actual data
        field_data_value * _field_data_values_array = NULL;

    try {
        parser->parse(xmlFile);

        DOMDocument* dom = parser->getDocument();

        DOMNodeList * dom_node_list = dom->getChildNodes();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dom_node_list->getLength(); i++) {

            walk_DOM(dom_node_list->item(i), _file_observational_area);
        }

        get_data(_file_observational_area, xmlFile, 0, 0, 0, _field_data_values_array);



    } catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
                << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);
        return -1;
    }

    }
```

**The walk_dom() relevant snippet, which calls parse_dom():**

```
void walk_DOM(DOMNode * dom_node, file_observational_area * _file_observational_area) {



    if (_file_observational_area) {
        _file_observational_area = parse_dom(dom_node, _file_observational_area);
}
```

**parse_dom() functions relevant snippet:**

```
 /*<Field_Delimited>*/
                                                        if (XMLString::equals(currentElement->getNodeName(), XMLString::transcode("Field_Delimited"))) {

                                                            /*<Field_Delimited>
                                                           <name>enc4</name>
                                                           <data_type>ASCII_Real</data_type>
                                                           <unit>rad</unit>
                                                           <description>Joint 4 encoder counts [RA_DOF]</description>
                                                           </Field_Delimited>*/

                                                            /*<Field_Delimited>*/
                                                            XMLCh* tag_Field_Delimited_name = XMLString::transcode("name");
                                                            string tag_Field_Delimited_name_val;
                                                            XMLCh* tag_Field_Delimited_data_type = XMLString::transcode("data_type");
                                                            string tag_Field_Delimited_data_type_val;
                                                            XMLCh* tag_Field_Delimited_unit = XMLString::transcode("unit");
                                                            string tag_Field_Delimited_unit_val;
                                                            XMLCh* tag_Field_Delimited_description = XMLString::transcode("description");
                                                            string tag_Field_Delimited_description_val;
                                                            DOMElement * field_delimited_element = NULL;
                                                            cout << "<Field_Delimited> DETECTED\n";


                                                            DOMNode * child = currentElement->getFirstElementChild();


                                                            while (NULL != child) {


                                                                if (DOMNode::ELEMENT_NODE == child->getNodeType()) {
                                                                    if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_name, child->getNodeName())) {
                                                                        _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());
                                                                        //strcpy(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name, XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent()));
                                                                        cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_name_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name << "\n";
                                                                    }
                                                                    if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_data_type, child->getNodeName())) {
                                                                        _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].data_type = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());
                                                                        //strcpy(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].data_type, XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent()));
                                                                       cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_data_type_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].data_type << "\n";
                                                                    }
                                                                    if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_unit, child->getNodeName())) {
                                                                        _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].unit = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());
                                                                        // strcpy(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].unit, XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent()));
                                                                        cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_unit_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].unit << "\n";
                                                                    }
                                                                    if (XMLString::equals(tag_Field_Delimited_description, child->getNodeName())) {
                                                                        _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].description = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());
                                                                         //strcpy(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].description, XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent()));
                                                                        cout << "Debug: tag_Field_Delimited_description_val:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].description << "\n";
                                                                    }
                                                                }


                                                                child = child->getNextSibling();

                                                            }//end while <Field_Delimited> has siblings

                                                        }//end  /*<Field_Delimited>*/



}
```

**The logs show expected behavior for** `parse_dom()` **Im able to get the correct values via** `XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent())` & **set  the values using** `_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());`.

**THE PROBLEM: However, in `void get_data()`, the values of the char go missing or are corrupted, see relevant snippet**:

```
                                                            for (int field_record_index = 0; field_record_index < _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->fields; field_record_index++) {
                                                                if (NULL != _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited) {

                                                                    cout << "<Field_Delimited> number:" << field_record_index << "\n";

                                                                    //MISSING or corrupted name
                                                                    cout << "name :" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].name << "\n";

                                                                    //MISSING or corrupted datatype
                                                                    cout << "data_type:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].data_type << "\n";
                                                                    //MISSING or corrupted unit
                                                                    cout << "unit:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].unit << "\n";
                                                                    //MISSING or corrupted description 
                                                                    cout << "description:" << _file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[field_record_index].description << "\n";

                                                                                                                                }
```

This is how I allocated memory for dynamic strings:

```
 /*=============================================================================
    Function        malloc_field_delimited
    Description:    allocated memory for _record_delimited->_field_delimited
     *                  dynamic array 
    References:       
    Inputs:         
    Output:            
    ==========================================================*/
    field_delimited * malloc_field_delimited(field_delimited * _field_delimited, int number_of_fields) {

         _field_delimited = (field_delimited*) malloc(sizeof (field_delimited) * number_of_fields);

         field_delimited * field_delimited_ptr = _field_delimited; 
        if (_field_delimited) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_fields; i++) {
                (field_delimited_ptr + i)->name = (char *)  malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);
                (field_delimited_ptr + i)->data_type = (char *)  malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);
                (field_delimited_ptr + i)->description = (char *)  malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);
                (field_delimited_ptr + i)->unit = (char *)  malloc(sizeof (char) * 256);


            }
        } else {
            printf("malloc_field_delimited(), unable to allocate memory, exiting!");
            exit(1);
        }

        return _field_delimited;
    }
```

I  also attempted to use `memset()` however it was useless, the same issue.

**Why do char values in get_data() go missing & how can I resolve this?**

I would like to stick to using dynamically allocated strings via `char *` , rather than using strings.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Sticking to `malloc()` and `free()` when you have `std::string` available is like walking 1000 miles when you have a car you can drive.  You can do it, but unless you have a really good reason, you are causing yourself huge amounts of unnecessary pain.

Comment: Just saying, `_file_observational_area = parse_dom(dom_node, _file_observational_area);` in `walk_DOM`, the resulting pointer value is not conveyed back to the caller, so I'm not sure what you're hoping for there. And I concur with Jeremy; Why you're using this insanity rather than proper collections of `std::string` boggles the imagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name = XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent());
```

You are overriding your pointers, losing memory you allocated before. you should use strcpy instead.

```
    strcpy(_file_observational_area->_table_delimited->_record_delimited->_field_delimited[Record_Delimited_index ].name, XMLString::transcode(child->getTextContent()));
```